# Calculating covariance of a linear combination of random variables, negative random variable?

Tags: random-variable, covariance

I have three random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ that are normally distributed each with different means $\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3$ and share the same variance $\sigma^2$. I want to find the covariance of $(X_1-\bar{X}, \bar{X})$, where $\bar{X}$ is the average of the three random variables.

I did the following , $Cov(X_1-\bar{X}, \bar{X})= Cov(X_1, \bar{X})+Cov(-\bar{X}, \bar{X})$. Now I am unsure if I can apply the formula $Cov(X_1, \bar{X})=E[X_1\bar{X}]-E[X_1]E[\bar{X}]$ because $\bar{X}$ and $X_1$ are not independent? Also I am not sure how to handle $Cov(-\bar{X}, \bar{X})$, because of the negative sign inside. Is it still $Var(\bar{X})$?

Comment: For additional answers, please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcovariance%5D+combination).

Comment: @whuber There really is no explanation for my question in the question you cited as duplicate. Yes it's about doing the same task but I am stuck on a different problem.

Comment: Trivial mathematical variations of the same problem are considered duplicates.  In your case, $X_1-\bar X = (2/3)X_1 - (1/3)X_2 - (1/3)X_3$ is a linear combination and, similarly, $\bar X$ is a linear combination.  The *only* way in which your question differs consists in the actual values of the numbers and not in the solution itself.  If the similarity is not clear, then please investigate the search link I posted: the relevant formulas are quoted, explained, and illustrated in many threads on this site.